# WebStorm hints me the TS error (TS2705) when I use jest(ts-jest async/await test)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, jestjs

Packages:
jest
ts-jest
@types/jest

IDE:
WebStorm

When I use the [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#async-await) asynchronous test there is a TS error (TS2705) that I cannot resolve. But this hint does not affect the `jest` command.

[image]

There is the same error when I use the smallest test:

```
import {} from 'jest';

test('async test',async ()=>{

});
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports =  {
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "json",
        "node"
    ],
    globals:{
        'ts-jest':{
            // I have the same behavior when I delete this line
            "tsConfigFile": "./tsconfig.json"
        }
    }
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
    "node"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
  ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,


    "rootDirs": ["."],
    "outDir":"./dist",
    "experimentalDecorators":true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "watch":false
  },
  "include":[
    "./app/**/*.ts",
    "./config/**/*.ts",
    "./app.ts",
    "./preload.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./dist/**/*.*"
  ]
}
```

How can I resolve this IDE error hint?

Comment: adding `"es2015"` to `"lib"` in `tsconfig.json` should fix the issue, but you do have it added already. How many `tsconfig.*.json` ( `tsconfig.app.json`,  `tsconfig.test.json`, etc.) files do you have in your project?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Only one tsconfg.json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If TypeScript Service is enabled in **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**, it uses the  nearest `tsconfig.json` current file is included in, scanning folders from the file dir up to the project root. If no `tsconfig.*.json` files current file is included in are found, default configuration is used for file linting.
Please note the "*include*" section in your root `tsconfig.json`:

```
"include":[
    "./app/**/*.ts",
    "./config/**/*.ts",
    "./app.ts",
    "./preload.ts"
  ],
```

"tests" directory where your spec files reside is not included in your TypeScript project. See [tsconfig.json documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

*If the "files" and "include" are both left unspecified, the compiler defaults to including all TypeScript (.ts, .d.ts and .tsx) files in the containing directory and subdirectories except those excluded using the "exclude" property. If the "files" or "include" properties are specified, the compiler 
will instead include the union of the files included by those two properties.*

So, no appropriate `tsconfig.json` file for your spec files is found (you must have seen a warning 'no root tsconfig.json found' in typeScript console). As a result, default compiler preferences, that don't include `"es2015"` library, are used - thus the error.
Including test files in your root config or adding a separate `tsconfig.json` with appropriate settings in "tests" directory should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved.

But do not understand the principle.

[image]

I added a tsconfg.json file in the `tests` directory and solved it.